# How to insert a batch of entities into Azure Table?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm inserting a batch of entities whitch have the same partition key using `TableBatchOperation` class. However, I may add more than 100 entities into my TableBatchOperation object. I would like to know what happens when I do the execute? Does this insertion operation fails or it automatically adds the entities in group of 100 entities?

Comment: I've noticed you've been posting a lot of questions about Azure Table lately, so here's some resources which might allow you to answer some of your own questions as well as help you meet the research requirement in the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [General Table Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423.aspx), [Perf Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#tables), [Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our .Net library this will fail on the server with a message saying that there is a problem with you 99th operation. Coming in v7.0 we will fail client-side with a more helpful error message.

For our client libraries such as Java, client-side validation is already built in.

Comment: So I should divide them into groups of 100 entities in the client side myself?

Comment: Yes, you would need to detect when your batch is going to exceed the limit and separate out any remaining operations into another call.